# AngularJS File Upload to Backend Express Server

Tags: html, angularjs, file-upload, express, angularjs-directive

I am trying to do a file upload using angularjs, using angular-file-upload library (https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload)

Here is my code

```
// ===============================My HTML File===========================
<input type="file" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)">


// ===============================My Controller==========================
var $scope.formObj = {
  name: "Test"
};

var fileToUpload;

$scope.onFileSelect = function (file) {
 fileToUpload = file[0];
};

// POSt request to /api/items
$scope.addItem = function() {
  console.log($scope.formObj);
  $scope.upload = $upload.upload({
   url: '/api/items',
   method: 'POST',
   data: { myObj: $scope.formObj },
   file: fileToUpload
  }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
   console.log("success");
  });
};


// ================================My Backend=============================

// This is the function that will receive POST request to /api/items
exports.create = function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body); // req.body is just an empty object. ==> {}

  // apparently, I found all the data to be in req._readableState.buffer[0]
  // in the form of a buffer
  var buffer = req._readableState.buffer[0];

  // trying to console.log the buffer.toString, resulting in something similar to this
  // { name: "Test", image: Object }
  console.log(buffer.toString());

  return res.send(200);
};
```

So my backend received the formObj with all its properties and values, however, the actual file data itself, whether in the form of buffer, or base64, or whatever, never gets received.

I wonder why.  This is my first time working with file uploading, so I don't understand the concept.

Please point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Latest version of Express, you'd notice that

`app.use(express.multipart());` is no longer bundled with express.

So do the following configuration changes. in express.js

```
var multer = require('multer');

app.use(multer({ dest: './uploads/'}));
```

You'd find that after doing this you would find the data and file , in req.body req.file respectively.

Hope it helps